# Axios Post request returning HTML code instead of JSON data

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, axios, graphql

I am doing a simple axios post request using GRAPHQL, it is returning a HTML code instead of JSON data.

This request correctly on Postman but returning HTML code here.

My code:

```
const qs = require('qs');
const axios = require('axios');

const headers = {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": process.env.TOKEN
};

const getData = (id) => {
    let q_type = `
    query getAllData {
        org(id: ${id}) {
            .....        }
    }`;

    finalData(q_type).then((res) => res);
}

const finalData = async (query_name) => {
    const result = await axios.post(
        process.env.ENDPOINT,
        { headers: headers },
        { query: qs.parse(query_name) })
        try {
            console.log(result.data);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
};

getData(123);
```

When I run `node index.js`, I am expecting JSON data. But I am getting:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Login</title>
........
```

I know my endpoint and token are correct because I am getting JSON data back on Postman. What am I missing here?

Comment: You can export the Postman request and observe the output json file. It might hint you to where is the problem.